# Access TextReader as a Stream

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I would like to have similar functionality for a TextReader that a Stream has.  Specifically the ability to set position in the stream.  Is there any way to change a TextReader into a stream?

I would like to accept a TextReader but access it like a Stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in the general case. Not all `TextReader` instances are based on streams.

Also, a `TextReader` is based on lines of text, where the line terminators may not be the sort that you can back up over.

Comment: I see, it looks like I'll have to restrict use to a Stream.  Thanks I had a feeling this was the case.

Comment: Are you dealing with Unicode or other character sets which are not single-byte character sets? If so, then  you won't be able to do this in a simple manner.

Comment: I plan to add parameters so that the Encoding can be specified.  My main purpose is to be able to take a Stream and index the lines in the stream.  Of course I'll have to check the encoding type to know if it contains single byte characters or two-byte characters.

Comment: Or "whatever-byte" characters. Just let the encoding break it into lines. Maybe read it with TextReader.ReadLine, use Encoding.GetBytes to get the bytes from the string according to the specified encoding, then add the bytes to a MemoryStream, record the index, then maybe add a "new line".

Comment: For convert ( is not access) you may use this: 

string content = textReader.ReadToEnd();
     Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content));

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain a Stream through the use of the StreamReader class. StreamReader is a subclass of TextReader so you can easily access its stream property by doing the following:

```
    TextReader reader = File.OpenText("C:\\todo.txt");
    Stream stream = ((StreamReader)reader).BaseStream;
```

Depending on what you need to do, you may also be able to just use the StreamReader class.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Suppose your todo.txt contains a single char **`ş`** (239,187 in UTF8). If you set the position to 1 and try to read a char you will get garbage.

Comment: While this would work with an underlying StreamReader class returned by File.OpenText(...) it does not work with all TextReader objects such as StringReader.  The problem I have is that I want to allow a stream to any type of text type object, in memory or on disk.

Comment: True - you would need to have an underlying stream opened where your TextReader was originally obtained.

Answer (score 1):

Like StreamReader.

[StreamReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)

Regarding encoding

[StreamReader Constructor (String, Encoding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456.aspx)

Regarding stream

[StreamReader Constructor (Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at.aspx)

If you need to accept it as a TextReader then you are limited.
Are you really limited to TextReader as input?
In a comment you state any type of text.